# How to set distance between two UITextFields in UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am using a `UIAlertController` to present a dialog with two `UITextField`s. How do I set distance the TextFields in `UIAlertController`?

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:
        ^(UITextField *textField) {
      textField.placeholder = @"Nick Email";
      textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
      textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
      textField.text=username;
      textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;}];
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

  textField.placeholder = @"Full Name";
  [textField setKeyboardType : UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
  textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

  textField.text=email;
  textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}];
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UIAlertController** views are simple and **not to be customizable**. if you need then  add the customize UIView or present modal Controllers or then go for any thirdparty

Comment: Thanks you so much! but can change color of black border abow?

Comment: I suggest you to use [PMAlertController](https://github.com/Codeido/PMAlertController) that is a small library that allows you to substitute Apple's uncustomizable UIAlertController, with a beautiful and totally customizable alert.